# Linear combination of invertible matrices which is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two n×n matrices such that $\det(A)>0$ and $\det(B)<0$. Then show that there is a real number $t$ which is between $0$ and $1$, such that $tA+(1-t)B$ is singular.
I have no idea how to solve this. It looks similar to convexity but how can we define convexity of set of matrices?

Comment: You can consider the continuous function $\det(tA+(1-t)B)$.

Comment: I assume the underlying field is the reals, but what if it's, say, $Q$, or some extension of $Q$ in $\Bbb R$? I assume the theorem's still true in that case, but the continuity argument falls apart (or at least needs some more work). Hmmm.

Comment: @JohnHughes the theorem is not true over $\mathbb Q$: take $A=I_2$, $B=\pmatrix{0&2\\1&0}$. Then $tA+(1-t)B$ is singular only for two values of $t$, both are irrational.

Answer (score 3):

If

$A, B \in M_n(\Bbb R), \tag 1$

that is, $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ *real* matrices, then evidently the function

$t \mapsto tA + (1 - t)B \tag 2$

is continuous from $[0, 1]$ to $M_n(\Bbb R)$; and since

$\det:M_n(\Bbb R) \to \Bbb R \tag 3$

is also continuous, the composition

$f(t): t \mapsto tA + (1 - t)B \mapsto \det(tA + (1 - t)B) \tag 4$

a function from $[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$, is itself in fact continuous; furthermore we have

$f(0) = \det(B) < 0, \tag 5$

and

$f(1) = \det(A) > 0; \tag 6$

it now follows from the intermediate value theorem that

$\exists t_0 \in (0, 1), \; f(t_0) = 0, \tag 7$

that is

$\det(t_0A + (1 - t_0)B) = f(t_0) = 0. \tag 8$