# Zero determinant of a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

[Linear combination of invertible matrices which is singular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503554/linear-combination-of-invertible-matrices-which-is-singular) says that if $\det A < 0$ and $\det B > 0$, then there's a real number $t$ with $tA + (1-t)B$ singular.

Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are real matrices, the natural proof is to look at 
$$
f(t) = \det (tA + (1-t)B)
$$
and apply the intermediate value theorem to find a $t$ for which $f(t) = 0$, and you're done.

Here's my question: What if we don't assume we're working over the reals? In particular:

> Let $F$ be a subfield of the reals, and $A$ and $B$ be matrices with
>   entries in $F$, $\det A < 0, \det B > 0$. Must there be an element 
>   $t \in F$ with $\det (tA + (1-t)B) = 0$ ?

I have a feeling that the answer's either "no" or "obviously, yes," but at the moment I have no idea which.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take subfield $\mathbb Q$ and
$$
A = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 1 \\
1 & -2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
B = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I get the linear combination as 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 + t & 1 \\
1 & 2 - 4t
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and singular for some irrational $t \; , \;$
 when $$  4 t^2 + 6t - 3 = 0 $$

Comment: Thanks, Will...Excellent. I somehow had it in mind that the expression would be linear in $t$, so the real solution would also end up in the subfield... I knew that wasn't right, but was too tired to see an example that shows why it was wrong. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes  happy to help. Get some sleep.